# How to show the target items in ListView to the top of the screen

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I am writing an android app which contains a listview with some items (fetch by database, can be 100+)
i would like the scroll the listview to display the specific item (let say position x in the listview)
i used

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
    }
});
```

the view has scrolled. but it stopped once the item appear. (the item is now displayed at the bottom of the screen)
i think better design is to display the item at the top of the screen or at least at the middle of the screen.
How can i do this?

I am now finding the way to find out the index of the listview which is really visible in the screen.
I have tried getFirstVisiblePosition() but it seems always return 0.

Answer (score 1):

You will find [`setSelection()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29) works better than `smoothScrollToPosition()`. If you are loading the data backing the ListView in the background, you will want to delay issuing the `setSelection()` until the data has been loaded.

`getFirstVisiblePosition()` works fine for me, but again is only useful once all the data has been loaded. Here is some code I use for a ListView that displays data fetched from a remote site:

```
    // the list has been updated, fix the selection. loadFinished will be true if there are no phantom placeholders left.
protected void listLoaded(boolean loadFinished) {
    // if the user has scrolled or we previously completed resetting the position, do nothing
    if(wasScrolled)
        return;
            // if we were restored from saved data, reload that data now.
    if(listState != null) {
        postListView.onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
        listState = null;
    } else if(initialPos >= 0) // if we had a specific initial position, set it now
        setSelection(initialPos);
    else if(postId >= 0)  // or if there is a specific post ID we want displayed
        setSelection(postAdapter.getPostPosition(postId));
    else // otherwise scroll to the first unread post
        setSelection(postAdapter.getFirstUnread());
    if(loadFinished) // if all data has been loaded, set a flag to prevent this being repeated
        wasScrolled = true;
}
```